# RabbitMQ clients orphaned in the server because of K8S SIGTERM

Tags: python, kubernetes, rabbitmq, pika

We have a bunch of pods that use RabbitMQ. If the pods are shut down by K8S with SIGTERM, we have found that our RMQ client (Python Pika) has no time to close the connection to RMQ Server causing it to think those clients are still alive until 2 heartbeats are missed.

Our investigation has turned up that on SIGTERM, K8S kills all in- and most importantly OUTbound TCP connections, among other things (removing endpoints, etc.) Tried to see if any connections were still possible during preStop hooks, but preStop seems very internally focused and no traffic got out.

Has anybody else experienced this issue and solved it? All we need to do is be able to get a message out the door before kubelet slams the door. Our pods are not K8S "Services" so some [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62567844/kubernetes-graceful-shutdown-continue-to-serve-traffic-during-termination) didn't help.

Steps to reproduce:

1. add preStop hook sleep 30s to Sender pod
2. tail logs of Receiver pod to see inbound requests
3. enter Sender container's shell & loop curl Receiver - requests appear in the logs
4. `k delete pod` to start termination of Sender pod
5. curl requests immediately begin to hang in Sender, nothing in the Receiver logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tested this extensively and found that new EKS clusters, with Calico installed (see below) will experience this problem, unless Calico is upgraded. Networking will be immediately killed when a pod is sent SIGTERM instead of waiting for the grace period. If you're experiencing this problem and are using Calico, please check the version of Calico against this thread:

https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/4518

If you're installing Calico using the AWS yaml found here:
https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/tree/master/config

Be advised that the fixes have NOT landed in any of the released versions, we had to install from master, like so:

```
  kubectl apply \
  -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/master/config/master/calico-operator.yaml \
  -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/master/config/master/calico-crs.yaml
```

and we also upgraded the AWS CNI for good measure, although that wasn't explicitly required to solve our issue:

```
  kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/v1.8.0/config/v1.8/aws-k8s-cni.yaml
  kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/v1.9.1/config/v1.9/aws-k8s-cni.yaml
```

Here's a bunch of [confusing documentation from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-vpc-cni.html) that makes it seem like you should switch to use new AWS "add-ons" to manage this stuff, but after an extensive discussion with support, was advised against

Answer (score 1):

TERM kills nothing, it's up to your application to decide how to handle it. SIGKILL is sent some time later which does forcibly nuke the process but 1) it also closes all sockets which RMQ can detect and 2) you control how long the container has to close cleanly via terminationGracePeriodSeconds

Comment: It isn't about our process, which we determined is still alive, it's that the process of K8S taking the pod out of service simultaneously sends TERM (which we can handle) but _also_ terminates network to the pod as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination): " At the same time as the kubelet is starting graceful shutdown, the control plane removes that shutting-down Pod from Endpoints"

Comment: That has zero to do with disabling the network like you seem to be imagining. Endpoints are API objects, they have no effect on sockets themselves. Removing the Endpoint value does (a few ms later) mean your Pod is yanked from any kube-proxy load balancers or other things using the Endpoint data but you're talking about outbound connections, not an inbound load balancer. I think you've just found a red herring and convinced yourself it was related :)

Comment: While I would love to agree, our empirical testing begs to differ. I've added our testing steps to the original question.

Comment: Either you've found a major bug in Kubernetes pod handling that no one has ever noticed before, or there is something weird specific to your setup. The first is always possible but my money would be on the second.

Comment: Calico is the culprit: https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/4518
Removing it resulted in the expected behavior (pods could still communicate during TERM). I'll report back on upgrades.

Comment: Upgrading Calico fixed the issue.